# File does not exist error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, esp-12f

I have an ESP-12F module and installed the ESP-12 from this board manager link http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json.

This image contain the settings [these are my Arduino settings for ESP-12F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTN0J.png) .

It always gives an error message like:

```
"Arduino: 1.6.12 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, 115200, 4M (3M SPIFFS)"

 exec: "C:\\Users\\SUM\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++": file does not exist
    Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
 "

Note: Power source is USB cable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ exists in the given path ?

Comment: i don't know however the matter is solved.... Tnxs

Answer (score 1):

You need to run 'get.py' in  esp8266/tools/ This will download the missing files.

The full git installation instruction are [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#using-git-version).